# How can I make the use of modern weapons and technology unreliable on a planet?

Tags: technology, weapons, environment

Let me say up front this is not a hard sci-fi book, it's character and story driven. So I just need some plausible answers.

I'm trying to restrict characters to using basic weaponry and technology. One way is having a desert planet torn by continual dust and sand storms. Visibility is often low and aiming a projectile weapon would be difficult. Basically wind is almost always blowing. Because of that, the natives never really made projectile weapons. They stuck to things like spears/pikes, even putting charges into them like cattle prods. And of course knives and such.

But if I came from Earth, would this be enough to deter me from say using a regular gun? (Let's assume lasers/plasma guns are not around yet).

Would the constant blowing sand and dust build up static electricity, and if so, would it be enough to mess with your tech? Such as communications, whether radio, wireless or satellite.

I've read a couple posts on magnetic fields, and they quickly got very scientific. I was thinking of adding a strong magnetic field to also make technology act weird. Could it be strong enough to do that, but not so strong that it would actually pull metal items around?

Any other ideas on making modern tech be unreliable would be great. Again, doesn't have to be overly scientific.

This is supposed to be a colony planet where people have settled to farm a valuable local resource.

Comment: Do you want to limit the use of weapons (technology is maybe a bit broad ...) only outside or have the natives of the planet not invented inside yet or do you want a solution where people also wouldn't use a gun inside let's say a building or a cave or wherever *people* live?

Comment: I suppose you could use a gun inside. But most of the activity here takes place outside, that's the key. The natives do not build houses per se, although the spend some time in caves.

But I also want technology to be limited. When characters go out into the main desert area, I want them to be on their own, with no real hope for using technology like GPS, phones, networks, etc. 

The idea is that it's almost like the wild west on the colony. Yes it's the future, but I don't want them having all the comforts of Earth. Plus, there's no network of satellites orbiting the planet.

Comment: Have you considered that earth people just didn't bring e.g. a gun with them? Every piece of equipment people shoot into space is carefully selected and only brought up if absolutely needed. A gun certainly wouldn't be on my list for things to take on a space trip. Also there are still large parts on earth where technology does not work reliably. For example, in my living room I do not have cell phone reception. For modern technology to work you need to invest heavily into infrastructure. I would think about it if this problem can't be solved in a straight-forward way

Comment: Fair thought, but let's say bringing stuff isn't an impediment. There are jump ships that can take significant enough loads. If they wanted guns, they could have them.

Comment: Re: orbital infrastructure -- it's a lot easier to put infrastructure in orbit around something when you're arriving from space vs. when you're stuck on the rock :)

Comment: define "technology" do you want cars to work, computers, stoves, radio, zippers, ect. Also how habitable is the planet, there is no way to make a planet on which guns will not work and yet have people survive without wear space suits.

Comment: @Shalvenay oh, good point.

Comment: @John Guns WORK fine. It's not worth trying to use them due to the environment - visibility, wind, etc. Sure, you can blow someone away inside. But most everything happens outside. When I say "technology" I guess I am really talking about microcomputers - think of advanced smart phones, hand held computers, that sort of thing. Think of the planet is mostly desert, but human compatible.

Comment: And guns might work SOMETIMES. But if you are counting on them saving your life, you'd not want to take the chance. (I suppose I could also outlaw them on a colonist planet. Not sure people would really go for that if they are risking their lives to live on some far flung planet. )

Comment: @MajorTom I wouldn't try to come up with atmospheric conditions that make firearms outright unusable. Severe wind and reduced visibility may drastically reduce the effective range of modern weapons, but they'll still beat the heck of out of close combat. Finding ways to make them logistically non-viable is probably a better bet.

Comment: If the wind is slow enough so people can still stand, then guns are still very accurate at anything but the longest range.

Comment: Here is an important question, does this need to be a constant condition or something that happens once, you could easily have the first group on the planet find it to cold to fire a gun without risk of he barrel shattering, but every group after that will bring cold tolerant alloy weapons.

Comment: Lots of good food for thought here. I may have to revise the stance on guns.

Comment: I strongly disagree with your first sentence "Let me say up front this is not a hard sci-fi book, it's character and story driven." Hard/soft sf is defined by the technology, not by the plotting and characters. Hard sf can be character and story driven.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could simply have the dust with a large iron ore content. [Magnetite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetite) forms natural magnets, which sounds like exactly what you want.

Dust also affects precision parts, like the barrel and chambers of firearms. Sufficient dust (sand/grit) will scrape the barrels and ruin the rifling, turning your modern firearm into a musket. Smaller amounts can affect the moving parts within the weapon. Simpler firearms are more resistant to such damage, but modern automatic weaponry would be badly damaged by [iron sand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ironsand) flying around.

Comment: That's a good suggestion. I will look into that. Would that affect communications?

Comment: It should; thousands of tiny magnets flying around will create at lot of interference. Plus the fact that the dust is conductive, like iron filings, so it will short out exposed contacts

Comment: "turning your modern firearm into a musket" - or, much more likely, an IED.

Comment: And turning to rust in your lungs. That will work out great.

Comment: @KeithMorrison: Coughing is a thing. Solid particles entering your lungs will be expelled, or you will asphyxiate well before _rusting_ becomes a concern

Comment: I was talking about asphyxiation.

Answer (score 3):

If you're not too sold on the idea of a desert planet, a thick rainforest jungle would do the trick. Just like in Vietnam, the dense forest would render the long-range and even beyond-visual-range capabilities of modern weapons nearly on pair with melee weapons, while the wet weather would quickly take a toll on nearly all kind of modern technology, even supposedly water-proof. Rain and trees would also hamper all kind of communications.

**EDIT**

As you want it to be a desert, I'd go with @nzaman answer (I had upvoted it even before writing my own answer). An idea I have had as an afterthought: if the gravity is not too high but the air pressure is similar to Earth - so that it is normally breathable by humans - you could have constant dust clouds in your desert.

The dust would create a fog reducing visibility to just a few meters away. In these conditions, firearms are not very useful - they need ammo, the dust spoils them quickly, and are not that good in very close combat, for they lack in stoping power (you can shot someone and he still can cut off your head with his sword before dying) and are prone to friendly fire in the mayhem of a melee. Communications would work unless you add the magnetite nzaman suggested, but it's not that useful either. How do you communicate your position when you can't see where you are? With no GPS, which depends of a network of already deployed satellites, the only way to find you is with triangularization of your signal, but you need to keep on transmitting to do that, and batteries run off - and you can't recharge them.

Comment: That's a good point. I'm entrenched in this desert idea, but maybe not so far that I couldn't change. How close could a desert desert-like area be to a rainforest?

Comment: @MajorTom Well, rainforests and deserts are like quite the most opposite biomas you can have, I'm afraid. I'll try my best in an edit, though.

Answer (score 1):

In many novels restrictions were made by some gatekeepers. It could be ancient aliens or just Intergalactic police - someone who implicitly or explicitly bans weapons on this planet.

For aliens it could be some mystic i.e. you don't need deep explanations.

- Shooter got reflected bullet
- There is some field around the planet. Every gun is got broken in this field.
- Desire to kill/shoot causes headache

There are some resons for explicit ban from humans. The rules so strict that it's almost impossible to get gun even in a grey market

- Scientists studying local culture so no modern technic allowed
- The planet is a wildlife sanctuary so no weapons at all. You could use petards at best. A predator could eat you but you can't hurt it
- It's too dangerous to get guns for aborigens

And mysterious reasons. Something strange happens and scientist don't know the answer:

- [Coriolis force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coriolis_force) acts unpredictably without clear reason. It makes aiming impossible
- Explosives explodes unpredictably

Answer (score 1):

### [Death World](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DeathWorld)

Agressive local life and remains of old technology.

- local animals will avenge any harm done to kin (think humans, [Anograch](http://blastron01.tumblr.com/post/153336276600/im-a-spider-so-what-war-1) , [Pig zombie](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Zombie_Pigman), or a certain [trope namer novel](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/Deathworld) by H.Harrsion). And with a growth factor of 100000% of the Earth's animal, you'll run out of any resources very quick, your defenses will be downed by walk-in tons of biomassa and your average supply chain is what, a single orbiter that can't even land in all that jungle. Zerg win.
- spirits don't like it and will haunt you for any harm
- there are omnipresent nanobots in the air. Once provoked, they'll go for your tech and YOU - ancient grey goo scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Important temperature changes.

- Movile parts often need lubricant, and the properties of a lubricant are highly dependent of the temperature; too cold and they solidify, too hot and they lose viscosity and their lubricant properties, maybe even to the point that they leak.
- Electronic components have operating temperature ranges, too. Too hot and chips overheat and even may fuse, capacitators may blow, etc. Too low and the current properties change, capacitators stop working, etc.

Comment: I thought about this as well for a second, but I believe that before there isn't any lubricant one can use and all electronics stop working, people would stop working as well.

Comment: @Raditz_35 -- yeah, people build electronics packages that get sent down oil wells with temps up to 200degC

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a planet with no metal to forge into weapons. albeit you could still use sticks and stones, it would be a far less dangerous world. That also solves your communication problems, no metal means no communication devices. Only metal they would have available is the metal that brought them there, and the metal they brought with them. Because I cant think of a way to make them unreliable and yet still support human life, a planet with no metal would provide a stalemate on any war. bullets are limited, swords and machete's would be rare.

Comment: Well, the colonists can bring metal. It doesn't have to be there.

Answer (score 0):

You could give the planet a strong magnetic field that will mess with computers, and possibly mess with the trajectory of bullets. Or put an magnetar in proximity.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is *far* too broad. You want to prevent both gunpowder and microprocessor operation? Well, consider Venus or perhaps living in the atmosphere of Jupiter or under the ice of Ganymede. As far as an environment in which humans can survive? I can't think of any in which we could survive and yet we couldn't design a gun to operate in. They'd be nearly useless in an oxygen rich underwater world (some (synthetic) liquids can hold enough oxygen for us to breath (arguable whether it would allow long term survival, but maybe we'd have tech for that...)). The lower explosive limit for hydrogen is 4%, but say 3% would do major damage to a lot of our technology. I'd guess it wouldn't be all that toxic to us, but I don't know that for sure. LD<sub>50</sub> for rats is ">1.5%" but 2% and 99.2% are both greater than 1.5 and there's a big difference between them. Hydrogen does a number on metals, I sure wouldn't want to use a gun exposed to high levels of it (it weakens steel, stainless steel, aluminum, and others). A really technologically nasty but possibly survivable atmosphere would be one containing a few % hydrogen and hey why not add some graphite dust (which would tend to short out electronics (if not really well sealed)?

Comment: I'm not sure you get what I am asking. I didn't say gunpowder doesn't work. I said projectile weapons should not be feasible due to the environment. I have that mostly nailed down. I'm more interested in preventing tech working in the desert.